# Is SO becoming too popular?

Tags: discussion, questions, homepage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stackoverflow is too popular.  How do I get new questions answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27076/stackoverflow-is-too-popular-how-do-i-get-new-questions-answered)

SO has become so popular that if you submit a question within about 20 minutes it's gone off the front page... and potentially 3 pages deep within an hour.

I know that you can edit your question and bubble it back to the top for another 15 minutes of fame but after a handful of times it gets tagged as a wiki.  Plus if everyone is editing their questions we're all fighting for what limited space there is in the top few pages.

Has any thought been given to how to better handle all this fantastic growth?

Answer (score 5):

Why is that a problem?

Questions need to be on the front page to get attention, more questions are now asked, because there are now more users, therefore it takes less time for a question to get attention than it did before.

The only way this could be a problem is if the ratio of number of questions asked to number of people watching the site for questions to answer massively increased, which I don't think it has.

Finally, there are plenty of people who don't have the same view of Stack Overflow as you - maybe they filter out tags they're not interested in, maybe their default view of Stack Overflow that they visit is that for a particular tag (e.g. I quite often go straight to http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django).

If you're really having problems, then read [how to get attention for your old unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions).

Comment: +1 and you can put a bounty on your question.

Comment: +1 I never honestly thought about filtering tags... d'oh!